# Hibernate:How to delete in cascade?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

i have the following classes:

```
//Product class
public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;

//Package Class
public class Package {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Product product;

private int quantity;
private char mode;
private String unity;
private String description;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Usuario user;

public class User {
    @Id
    private String email;
```

I can insert a product, an user and a package just doing:

```
    //.. (iniatilize product and user before and set in package object) 
    session.save(package);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

So why i can't delete an user ?

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail("valter@gmail.com");
    session.delete(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Gives me this error :

> Cannot delete or update a parent row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails

### What's wrong with my classes ?

Complete Entity User

```
@Entity
public class Usuario {
    @Id
    private String email;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

### }

```
@Entity
public class Package{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Product product;

    private int quantity;
    private char mode;
    private String unity;
    private String description;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User user;


@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
```

That's all entities envolved in the system.

@Bozho Based in what you say , it should be this way right?

```
@Entity
public class User{
    @Id
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Package> packages;
```

I'm trying to execute this method:

```
    private static void deleteUser() {
    Session session = new HibernateUtil().getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    try{

        User usuario = (Usuario) session.load(Usuario.class, "valter@gmail.com");
        session.delete(usuario);
        session.getTransaction().commit();


    }catch(HibernateException he){
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: show the complete `User` entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are creating a detached entity and trying to delete it, rather than fetching a complete entity from the DB. In this case, even if you have cascades defined, they won't work because and relationship of the `User` entity is not populated.

If the email is the primary key, then you should do the following:

```
User user = session.load(User.class, "foo@bar.com");
session.delete(user)
```

Even with that, if any other entity references a `User`, it will logically fail - the just look at the database constraints. You have multiple ways to fix this:

- map `List<Package>` in your user, thus making the relationship bi-directional. Thus you'll be able to set the cascade on the `User` side as well
- before deleting a user find (by a query) all packages that belong to him, and delete them.
- If the package does not have any other cascades, use an HQL query: `DELETE FROM Package WHERE user=:user"`.

Comment: @Bozho It doesn't work.
Keeps saying :

17:36:08  WARN [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 1451, SQLState: 23000
17:36:08 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`package`, CONSTRAINT `FK243B5492B92BA2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_email`) REFERENCES `user` (`email`))
17:36:08 ERROR [AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session

Comment: @Valter Henrique as I said, show the whole user entity. And entities that refer to it.

Comment: @Bozho sorry by that, i edit now. thanks by your attention friend.

Comment: @Valter Henrique I've shown two ways to do it, which one doesn't work, and how?

Comment: @Bozho the second way that you recommeded is a little expansive in terms of memory and perfomance , i had to list all packages to delete the user.

Comment: @Bozho is there something wrong with my entities ?
'Cause i can delete one user if he dont' have any package associated, but i can't delete if he does.

keep give the same error dude.

I just want to have a package that has one product, and this package is associated with an user.
And then when i delete this user, my package goes too.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: @Valter Henrique you just have dependenices. You have to delete all packages associated with a given user. If something else depends on a package - also delete it. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

you should add orphanRemoval = true.

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Usuario user;

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your package class also, like

```
private static void deleteUser(Package package) {
Session session = new HibernateUtil().getSession();
session.beginTransaction();

try{

    User usuario = (Usuario) session.load(Usuario.class, "valter@gmail.com");
    package.setUser(null);
    session.merge(package);
    session.delete(usuario);
    session.getTransaction().commit();


}catch(HibernateException he){
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}finally{
    session.close();
}}
```